# Have the bibliographic list styled differently (as a list, not as entries)

Tags: bibliographies, memoir

I am currently writing my thesis using the `memoir` class. Some references are needed, as with any academic document, citation is needed.

Currently, I am using the `amsplain` bibliography style, which is fine, I have used it in all the papers related to my thesis. But I found a minor difference in the bibliography *list* itself between the thesis and the papers.

In the papers, the bibliography is listed as `1. Author ...` and in my thesis it is listed as `[1] Author ...`

Is there any way to force memoir to produce `1.` rather than `[1]` in the bibliography list?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you provided a minimal example that others could copy and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this works

```
\setbiblabel{#1.\hfill}
```

in the preamble